# bs4 BeautifulSoup - can't find what looks like custom tag to save my life

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm admittedly beginner to intermediate with Python and novice to BeautifulSoup/web-scraping.  However, I have successfully built a couple of scrapers.  Normal tags = no problem (e.g., div, a, li, etc)

However, can't find how to reference this tag with .select or .find or attrs="" or anything:

..........
<react type="sad" msgid="25314120" num="2"
..........

I ultimately want what looks like the "num" attribute from whatever this ghastly thing is ... a "react" tag (though I don't think that's a thing?)?

Comment: Hi DigitalGangsta - welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your question! To get the best quality answers here, be sure to post what you've tried and why it's not working. Additionally, see this post on creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Specifically, html trees can be navigated using positional indices, but you don't include the context around this tag. Can you give us some more info?

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` works the same way as you'd find other tags such as `div`, `p` and `a` tags. Therefore, we search for the 'react' tag.

```
react_tag = soup.find('react')
```

Then, access the `num` attribute like so.

```
num_value = react_tag['num']
```

Should print out:

```
2
```

Comment: Thx a bunch for response.  I've tried all the "normal" methods I'm familiar with like .find() and none of them work.  I've tried precisely what you've described and it always just turns up nothing.  My html, java, css knowledge is pretty weak (to put it mildly on the last two), so I'm wondering if it's some kind of strange custom tag that behaves differently or isn't really a tag at all even though it looks like one?

Comment: Does the <react> tag appear on the raw web page you are scraping? If javascript is used on the page, the javascript code might be putting the tag into the html page dynamically upon loading it. If so, then you'll need to scrape the page like so: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-scrape-any-website-with-python-and-beautiful-soup-part-2-of-2-77560fcd30fc

Comment: I think this dynamic javascript is very likely what's happening, I'm going to read the link.  That you all so much for your patience and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

As per [bs4 Documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) `.find('tag')` returns the single tag and `.find_all('tag')` returns list of tags in html.

In your case if there are multiple react tags use this

```
for reactTag in soup.find_all('react'):
    print(reactTag.get('num'))
```

To get only first tag use this

```
print(soup.find('react').get('num'))
```

Comment: I probably did a poor job with my question, I guess ... my problem is it will not find the react tags ... know idea why.  I'm trying to "find_all" just like I do with any other tag and it just doesn't find them, was hoping somebody would know something I don't.

Comment: If I am not wrong your problem is you are not getting the list of react tag after using `.find_all('react')`.

Comment: I am getting the list.  I'm well versed in iterating through the lists that come from .find_all.  I do it all the time successfully.  I've also tried using .select in case it was some kind of CSS thing I'm less familiar with.  I'm new to stack overflow, so I don't know the best way to share code ... when I tried to paste some tags in, they were being interpreted as HTML.  I'll try posting some of my actual code tomorrow, but really appreciate y'all's responses.

Answer (score 0):

The user "s n" was spot on!  These are dynamically created javascript which I didn't know anything about, but was pretty easy to figure out.  Using the SeleniumLibrary in Python and a "headless" WebChromeDriver together, you can use Selenium selectors like Xpath and many others to find these tags.